# Where is the source code for ghc-prim?

Tags: haskell

It was not easy to find the repository in google or hackage.

Where can I find the source code?

Answer (score 2):

The source code for the `ghc-prim` package is here: http://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/tree/HEAD:/libraries/ghc-prim

(If that link breaks again, look here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0).

Note that the `GHC.Prim` module itself is defined internal to the compiler, and does not correspond to any `.hs` file: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/PrimOps.